# Fast In-memory search for multiple attributes

Tags: c#, search, data-structures

I have a list of in memory objects (around 50000-1 million) which have 6-7 properties (attributes).

the requirement is to filter this in-memory list with multiple attributes. A linear search allows me to do a O(N) seach on the list. Is there any faster way to do it with better data structure than a generic list?

I am using C#.NET 4.0.

Comment: Attributes collection is always same or maybe different for each request?

Comment: You need search as exact match or any other kind of search "substring" "greater" "lesser" etc.. ?

Comment: @Tona: It can be different.

Comment: @Tona It will always be an exact match only. Is there some tree structure which handles this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best I can suggest:

1. Make dictionary for each required attribute (separate dictionaries)
2. When you search, lookup each required dictionary separately one by one and
   choose list of minimal size
3. Iterate list of minimal size

If Attribute values without big amount of duplicates, this approach will be very usefull.
But if each attribute has a lot of duplicates this approach will be very bad.

**Possible improvement**: each list into dictionary possible sort and after use it for binary search by one of attributes.

Comment: There are going to be a LOT of duplicates in the attribute values :( this approach might end up being slower than O(N) because of the large intersections

Comment: I suggest without intersections. Read step 3. Just, choose minimal list and iterate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a helper library named IndexedList, 
you can download it from http://indexedlist.codeplex.com/
With this library you can add indexes on any field(s) of your object then perform fast searches in your list.
Default index implementation uses Dictionary for storing index data, you can change it too.
I have created this library for my own projects then i published that as an open source project newly.
I will be happy to hear your feedback about this library.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few seconds ago i read this: http://blog.bodurov.com/Performance-SortedList-SortedDictionary-Dictionary-Hashtable/

Seems the `SortedDictionary` might be your best bet as searching goes but since you want to search by multiple attributes this drops so if you want a good balance between searching and inserting for that large amount of data maybe a `SortedList` will yield better results at the cost of memory usage.

Comment: I have no requirement of inserting. The data is static and doesnt change. I just need the lookup to be faster than O(N)

Comment: @ganeshran Then try the SortedList, this should give you O(1)

Comment: For a sorted list, how can I sort on multiple attributes? If I sort on one attribute the rest of the data will be unsorted

Comment: Then i don't see another option to speed this filtering up other than using ConcurrentCollections and then parallelizing the filtering...